# Address another machine inside Azure by custom domain name

Tags: azure, dns, azure-web-app-service, azure-worker-roles

I have a sort of webview (PhantomJS) running on a Worker Role. The rendered html pages load quite a lot of images.

Initially the images loaded straight from Blob Storage, which worked fine. In order to reduce the size, I set up an image resizer which happens to run on an Azure Website for now.

For requests from outside Azure, resized images are served properly. However when I try to load these same images from the webview on the Worker, it doesn't get access.

Is it possible I can't use a custom domain inside Azure when sending requests from a Worker to a Website? Loading random images from the internet works, just not getting them directly from the Website.

**Update**

It turns out `MyDomain.com` doesn't work, but `MyDomain.azurewebsites.net` works. What's the rules here? Is it recommended to use the internal Azure domain?

Comment: You should post your update as an answer (and mark as such), so you can properly close this question.

Comment: I was hoping for some more info about why it is the way it is. I'd happily accept your answer if you can shine some light.